# No nontrivial cyclic modules imply module is simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I was reading a theorem: For a non-zero right $A$-module $N$, the following conditions are equivalent:

(i) $N$ is simple

(ii) $uA=N$ for all non-zero $u\in N$

I can understand (i) implies (ii), but I am stuck with (ii) implies (i).
What I understand is that (ii) means that any nonzero cyclic submodule of $N$ has to be the entire module $N$. But what about the non-cyclic submodules? Don't we have to consider them too to conclude $N$ is simple?
I believe I am missing something..

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $N$ satisfies $(ii)$ and let $M$ be a non-zero submodule of $N$. Take $0\ne m\in M$. By $(ii)$ $mA=N$, but since $M$ is a submodule, we also have $mA\subset M$. Therefore $$mA=N\subset M$$ i.e., $N=M$ and $N$ is simple.